# How to get maximum number of records per day? max(count) MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Good day!

I have a table:

```
create table table_1 (field_1 varchar (10),  timestamp datetime(3),  field_2  varchar (10));
```

Date format  yyyy-mm-ddthh:mm:ss.000z.

And i need to count the number of records per hour and get the maximum this number of these records per day.

Request:

```
select date_format(date,'%Y.%m.%d') as date, max(summ)  from (select date_format(timestamp,'%Y.%m.%d %H' ) as date, count(field_2) as summ from table_1 a where field_1 in (1) group by date) b group by date;
```

Result:

```
date        summ
2019.12.25  2
2019.12.25  3
2019.12.25  12
```

But i need sumthing like:

```
date        summ
2019.12.25  12
2019.12.26  15
2019.12.27  14
```

Comment: Specify MySQL version.

Comment: *Result:* ... *But i need sumthing like:* Provide INSERT INTO with sample data which gives and must give the posted outputs.

Comment: if you set up an sql fiddle you'll get answers pretty quick. better than the commands because it reduces barrier to entry.

Comment: @DanielFarrell: A fiddle is fine, if it's additionally provided to DDL and DML. But the DDL and DML should always be provided in the question itself. That way the question isn't depending on the fiddle site being available rendering it useless for future readers should the fiddle site go down.

Comment: yeah, sorry, didn't mean to suggest not putting data in the question.  Always put all the relevant data in the question, but fiddles make this verifiable and reproducible without me setting up sql tables myself.

Comment: @Akina version 8.0.19.  'load data infile 'C:/file.tsv' into table table_1 fields terminated by '\t' lines terminated by'\n' ignore 1 lines  (field_1, timestamp, field_2)  set timestamp = FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp/1000);'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use window functions with aggregation:

```
select t.*
from (select date_format(timestamp, '%Y.%m.%d %H') as date, count(field_2) as summ,
             row_number() over (partition by date(timestamp) order by count(field_2) desc) as seqnum
      from table_1 a
      where field_1 in (1)
      group by date, date(timestamp)
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ef154b481368f82c959a7ff0b569f76b) is a demonstration that the code runs correctly.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work, cause - 'select' is not valid at this position for this sever version. version - 8.0.19

Comment: @Riot . . . For the maximum that should be `desc` in the `order by`.

Comment: Yes, now its work, but result incorrect: `2019.12.25 20 1 1  2019.12.26 00 1 1` I solved its like this : `select date_format(date,'%Y.%m.%d') as date, max(summ) from (select date_format(date,'%Y.%m.%d') as date, summ from (select date_format(timestamp,'%Y.%m.%d %H' ) as date, count(field_2) as summ from table_1 f where field_1 in (1) group by date) v group by date) e group by date;` Result: `2019.12.25    12  2019.12.26    11` But its not beautiful solution.